# Boolean logic on sparse Scipy matrices

Tags: scipy

I have a sparse matrix:

```
B = sps.csc_matrix( (z , (row,column) )), shape = (N_x,N_y),dtype=int)
```

I would like to count the occurrences of the integer 2 column-wise.
However, B == 2 does not give a boolean sparse matrix.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of scipy are you using?  `B == 2` works in scipy 0.14.0.

Comment: Right, thanks. Update to Scipy v0.14 everyone!